# R script not rounding as intended when running in Terminal

Tags: r, rounding

Apologies if this question is remedial, I am new to R. I am trying to get my code to round to the second decimal. When I run in R I have no problem doing this, however when I put my code into my terminal it doesn’t round as intended, usually cutting off zeros or rounding to the first decimal. Any suggestions? See below for the code and the output of the code

I am using data package msleep

```
as.data.frame(Q1 <- msleep %>%
  filter(vore == "carni", conservation == "lc")%>%
  summarise(va=round(var(sleep_total), digits = 2)))
Q1
```

*Intended output:*
26.35

*my Output:*
26.3

```
na.omit(msleep)
as.data.frame(Q4 <- msleep%>%
  group_by(conservation)%>%
  summarise(mean_sleep = mean(sleep_total), var_sleep = var(sleep_total))%>%
  arrange(conservation == "cd"| conservation == "domesticated"| conservation == "en"| conservation == "lc"| conservation == "nt"| conservation == "vu")%>%
  mutate_at(vars(mean_sleep, var_sleep), funs(round(., digit = 2)))%>%
  head(6))
Q4
```

*intended output:*

```
1           cd       2.30      0.32
2 domesticated       7.58     14.46
3           en      13.03     39.45
4           lc      11.44     21.80
5           nt      12.97      3.84
6           vu       6.93     14.34
```

*my output:*

```
  conservation mean_sleep var_sleep
  <chr>             <dbl>     <dbl>
1 cd                 2.3       0.32
2 domesticated       7.58     14.5 
3 en                13.0      39.4 
4 lc                11.4      21.8 
5 nt                13.0       3.84
6 vu                 6.93     14.3
```

Comment: It's how tidyverse data frames (`tibble`s) are printed. The data is still intact, it's just the formatting

Comment: How do I fix this? I thought I did when I added as.data.frame() to the beginning??

Comment: You assign it first to `Q4` then do `as.data.frame`, just do that in different order.

Comment: You converted it back to a base data frame, which is one solution, but you didn't actually assign that back to Q4, because you called `as.data.frame` on the entire statement. Either do `Q4 <- as.data.frame(Q4)` or add the equivalent to the end of the other piped steps